# Cannot edit my Stack Overflow profile

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, edits

Getting this error always without telling me what the real problem is:

> Oops! There was a problem updating your profile:
>   unusual error updating your profile -- please try again!

I tried several times... any help appreciated :-)

Answer (score 2):

This generally means you have JavaScript disabled.

Comment: but how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought... try deleting your browser's temporary files and cookies.